# backbone.js, handlebars error : this._input.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to backbone.js and handlebars and I'm having a problem getting my template to render out the data.

Here is my collection and model data from tagfeed.js module:

```
// Create a new module.
  var Tagfeed = app.module();

  // Default model.
  Tagfeed.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        image : ''
    }
  });

  // Default collection.
  Tagfeed.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Tagfeed.Model,
    url : Api_get('api/call')
  });

  Tagfeed.TagView = Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "tagfeed/feed",
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(template, context) {
                return Handlebars.compile(template)(context);
    }
  });
```

Then in my router I have:

```
define([
  // Application.
  "app",

  // Attach some modules
  "modules/tagfeed"
],

function(app, Tagfeed) {

  // Defining the application router, you can attach sub routers here.
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      "index.html": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        var collection = new Tagfeed.Collection();

        app.useLayout('main', {
            views: {
                ".feed": new Tagfeed.TagView({
                    collection: collection,
                    model: Tagfeed.Model,
                    render: function(template, context) {
                        return Handlebars.compile(template)(context);
                    }
                })
        }
  });
    }
  });

  return Router;

});
```

THis successfully makes a call to the api, makes a call to get my main template, and makes the call to get the feed template HTML. If I don't include that render(template, context) function, then it renders on the page as the straight up HTML that I have in the feed template with the {{ name }} still included. however when its included, I get the error

```
TypeError: this._input.match is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

match = this._input.match(this.rules[rules[i]]);
```

and if I examine the variables that get passed into the appLayout views render function for `feed`, I see that the `template` var is a function, and the `context` var is undefined, then it throws that error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I know I have at least one problem here, probably more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using requirejs, you can use the text module to externalise your templates or better still pre-compile them and include them in your view. Check out http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro

E.g. using pre-compiled templates

```
// router.js
define(['views/tag_feed', 'templates/feed'], function(TagFeedView) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        // ...

    });

})

// tag_feed.js
define(['collections/tag_feed'], function() {

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        // ...

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(
                Handlebars.templates.feed({
                    name: '...'
                })
            );
        }   

     });

})
```

For reference I've created simple boilerplate for a backbone/require/handlebars setup https://github.com/nec286/backbone-requirejs-handlebars

Comment: The link to you boilerplate example is a 404 :(